# spark load, textFile how does it work under the hood

Tags: apache-spark

In spark with a cluster of 5 slaves, 1 driver and 1 master, what happens when a file is read from a one location not from hadoop cluster. Is the whole file read by the driver and then it cuts the files into chunks and sends it to each slave or it tells the slave to go the location and pick say 20% of the file and the second slave to pick the next 20% and so on.

Comment: what do you mean by 'what happens when a file is read from a one location not from hadoop cluster'? if you are running job in cluster mode and file is not available on cluster then you get exception FileNotFoundException.

Comment: its not in hadoop cluster but in amazon s3